# Jboss DataGrid shared L2 cache store suggestion required

Tags: caching, datagrid, jboss, infinispan

We are implementing JBoss Data Grid for caching service with two servers in distributed mode. We need to configure the L2 cache store which need to be shared by both servers, we prefer not to use a database store.

Can you please suggest which is the best secondary cache store (other than database store) for JBoss Data Grid?

Our requirement is all the evicted data from both servers should be written into the same L2 cache store. If one server goes down the other server should be able to retrieve the data from the shared cache store.

Comment: If you use distributed mode with numOwners=2 (default), both servers will share a copy of the data, so even if one crashes, you don't need to reload anything.

Comment: If the data needs to be shared, how about Replicated mode? http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#replicated_mode

Comment: Currently we are going live with 2 servers but we will soon increase the count to 5. When we have 5 servers we don't want the same data to be stored in all 5 servers (in replicated mode), that's whey we are going with distributed. We did some testing with numOwners=2 and found that the data is getting stored in both servers, so we are good with this approach. Thanks all for your response.